# Jacobian matrix for $f(h)=hh^Th$, where $h$ is an $m$ dimensional vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have a function $f(h)=hh^Th$, can we say $\nabla f(h)=2*hh^T + h^ThI_{m\times m}$, where $I_{m\times m}$ is an identity matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the differential gives
$$df = hh^Tdh + h(dh)^Th + dh (h^Th).$$
$df$ must be linear in $dh$, and usually for the derivative of vector-valued functions with respect to a vector it is possible through rearrangement to get that linear map in matrix form. For instance here, since $(dh)^Th$ is a scalar, as is $h^Th$, the above can be rewritten
$$df = hh^T dh + hh^Tdh+ h^Th dh = (2hh^T+h^ThI)dh$$
and it looks like your calculations were correct.

Comment: Can you explain why $h(dh)^Th=hh^Tdh$? Thanks.

Comment: $(dh)^Th$ is a scalar, so if I transpose it I leave it unchanged: $$(dh)^Th = [(dh)^Th]^T = h^T(dh).$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [Einstein summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), we have first by the product rule,
$$\partial_i (h_j h_k h_k) = \partial_i (h_j) h_k h_k + h_j \partial_i  (h_k) h_k + h_j h_k \partial_i (h_k),$$
then from repeated terms and the fact $\partial_i h_j = \delta_{ij}$ the expression,
$$\partial_i (h_j h_k h_k) = \delta_{ij} h_k h_k + 2 h_j h_k \delta_{ik}$$
and finally summing over $k$,
$$\partial_i (h_j h_k h_k) = \delta_{ij} h_k h_k + 2 h_j h_i,$$
since $\delta_{ik} h_k = h_i$ when summing over $k$.

This is equivalent to
$$\nabla (h h^T h) = h^Th I_n + 2hh^T.$$